# Form Table Alignment Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've seen this question in several different location on StackOverflow and elsewhere, I've tried just about a dozen different solution ranging from two separate tables, to a complex series of classes, to manually setting pixel widths.

Every one of them seemed to have one of the following problems. Everything would scroll, Nothing would scroll, or the Header fields would be completely out of alignment with the rest of the table.

The context here is a base webpage and form with a ready button (submit) upon clicking the button, and after validation, the form contents are sent to a PHP program that then (at this time) returns an additional table that is added to the form and an Update button is revealed. This additional table contains 100 repeated entries and so I need to have it scroll the contents of the table but keep the headers in place so that the user still knows what field correlates to what.

Here is a screenshot of what it currently looks like

[image: Current Condition]

And here is the code that generates it. **UPDATED to generated HTML instead of php -- Reduced to one row for brevity**

```
<section class=''>
  <div class='container'>
    <table id='list-table' class='main-list input-capable-list ui-widget-content' cellspacing='2' >
       <thead class='fixedHeader ui-widget-content'>
                <tr>
                      <th><b>From City</b><div><b>From City</b></div></th>
                      <th><b>From State</b><div><b>From State</b></div></th>
                      <th></th>
                      <th><b>To City</b><div><b>To City</b></div></th>
                      <th><b>To State</b><div><b>To State</b></div></th>
                      <th><b>RPM</b><div><b>RPM</b></div></th>
                      <th><b>Flat</b><div><b>Flat</b></div></th>
                      <th><b>MIN</b><div><b>MIN</b></div></th>
                      <th><b>Fuel(Y/N)</b><div><b>Fuel(Y/N)</b></div></th>
                      <th><b>Comments</b><div><b>Comments</b></div></th>                                     </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                   <tr>
                     <td><input id='FCITY0' class='entry city' type='text' name='FCITY0' size='30' maxlength='30' /></td>
                          <td width='30'><input id='FSTATE0' class='entry state' type='text' name='FSTATE0' title='Please enter a valid State Code' size='2' maxlength='2' /></td>
                          <td width='500'></td>
                          <td width='50'><input id='TCITY0' class='entry city' type='text' name='TCITY0' size='30' maxlength='30' /></td>
                          <td width='30'><input id='TSTATE0' class='entry state' type='text' name='TSTATE0' title='Please enter a valid State Code' size='2' maxlength='2' /></td>
                          <td width='50'><input id='RPM0' class='entryNum' type='text' name='RPM0' size='4' maxlength='7' /></td>
                          <td width='50'><input id='FLAT0' class='entryNum' type='text' name='FLAT0' size='6' maxlength='12' /></td>
                          <td width='50'><input id='MIN0' class='entryNum' type='text' name='MIN0' size='5' maxlength='12' /></td>
                          <td width='50'><input id='FUEL0' class='entry fuel' type='text' name='FUEL0' size='1' maxlength='1' /></td>
                          <td width='200'><textarea id='COMNTS0' name='COMNTS0' maxlength='200' rows='2' cols='30'></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
          </section>
<style>section {
                        position: relative;
                        border: 1px solid #000;
                        padding-top: 37px;
                      }
                      section.positioned {
                        position: absolute;
                        top:100px;
                        left:100px;
                        width:800px;
                        box-shadow: 0 0 15px #333;
                      }
                      .container {
                        overflow-y: auto;
                        height: 440px;
                      }
                      table {
                        border-spacing: 0;
                        width:100%;
                      }
                      td + td {
                        border-left:1px solid #eee;
                      }
                      td, th {
                        border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
                        padding: 10px 25px;
                      }
                      th {
                        height: 0;
                        line-height: 0;
                        padding-top: 0;
                        padding-bottom: 0;
                        color: transparent;
                        border: none;
                        white-space: nowrap;
                      }
                      th div{
                        position: absolute;
                        background: transparent;
                        padding: 9px 25px;
                        top: 0;
                        margin-left: -25px;
                        line-height: normal;
                        border-left: 1px solid #800;
                      }
                      th:first-child div{
                        border: none;
                      }


                </style>
```

I'm open to any and all suggestions and potential solutions but please keep in mind, I've tried many of the obvious solutions, and so far this is the closest I've gotten to it doing what I want.

Please note that the second set of headers listed below the ones at the top, scroll up with the rest of the table data. The idea is for it to be overlapped by the div (the headers at the top). See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/light/

Comment: Try adding `position:relative;` to `th`

Comment: @j08691 Updated .... Alon Eitan, that caused the div area to jump down on top of the th area in a wierd kind of double vision and now both of them scroll up with the table instead of one staying put.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the height of the container, in which you want to show tables then apply `overflow: scroll` to that container.

or

You can make header sticky at top by following code

```
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
```

Comment: Not sure on the first part if I understand you because it sounds like what I'm already doing.  Tried the position: fixed; width: 100%; and top: 0; and all that did was make the div section vanish and the th section still scrolls with the rest of the table.